# slds grid broken layout when screen narrows to less than 480px

Tags: aura, slds, slds-grid

I'm using slds-grid. On large form factor the grid has 2 columns & on Medium & small forms 1 column - truncated.
Issues:

1. When screen narrows less than 768px, the grid component is not shrinking relatively, Content goes out of display size.
2. When screen less than 480px, the grid should display only 1 column but its showing the default size of 2 columns and content goes out of screen. below are the images.

Did anyone faced this issue? Any ideas how to fix this? Appreciate any help on this..!

[image: Large size]

[image: Medium size]

[image: Small size]

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center master-container">
        <div class="popular-articles-container">
            <div class="header-container">
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <img src="{!$Resource.CourseraIcons + '/courseraIcons/popular-articles-star.png'}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="header-text-container">
                    <h3 class="header-text popularArticlesTooltip">{!$Label.c.Popular_articles}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasArticles}">
                <div class="articles-container">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.articles}" var="article">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-has-flexi-truncate" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
                                <li class="slds-truncate">
                                    <a href="{!article.link}" class="topic-link" target="_blank">
                                        {!article.label}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aura:if>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, how would you expect us to be able to help you?

Comment: sorry for that,  I've added my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using media query in CSS to solve the width issue,
and added extra slds class "slds-size_2-of-2" in the columns class and it solved the column issue when screen narrows.

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-size_2-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-has-flexi-truncate" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
```